# Blazor and JavaScript functions not recognized

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

In my Blazor project, I have a lot of tabs to display. I was looking for a solution and I found a nice `JavaScript` implementation with `jQuery` that is working for desktop and mobile. Here an example of the `jQuery` implementation

[image]

It is working quite smoothly, and it is exactly what I need. So, I started to create a component with Blazor to reuse it and share. I published my code with examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorScrollTabs).

The problem I face is related to `CascadingValue`. My component has a container called *ScrollTabs* and each single *Tab*. So, I can write in the application something like that

```
<ScrollTabs TabId="TabId1" OnTabChanged="OnTabChanged">
    <Tab Text="Tab 1" Value="Tab1">
        <h2>Content Tab 1</h2>
        <p>
            This is the content for the Tab 1. It is enabled.
        </p>
    </Tab>
</ScrollTabs>
```

The *ScrollTabs* container is quite simple

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    <div id="@TabId" class="scroll_tabs_theme_light">
        @foreach (Tab tabPage in Pages)
        {
            <span>
                @tabPage.Text
            </span>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        @ChildContent
    </div>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    private DotNetObjectReference<ScrollTabs>? dotNetHelper;

    [Parameter]
    public string? TabId { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Tab> OnTabChanged { get; set; }

    public Tab? ActivePage { get; set; }
    List<Tab> Pages = new List<Tab>();

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            dotNetHelper = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Helpers.setDotNetHelper", dotNetHelper);
        }

        // Setup the tabs
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", TabId);
    }

    internal void AddPage(Tab tabPage)
    {
        Pages.Add(tabPage);
        if (Pages.Count == 1)
            ActivePage = tabPage;

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Then *Tab* is define like

```
@if (Parent.ActivePage == this)
{
    @ChildContent
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public ScrollTabs? Parent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Parent), "TabPage must exist within a TabControl");

        base.OnInitialized();
        Parent.AddPage(this);
    }
}
```

Now, if I run the code with the `CascadingValue`, the *JavaScript* has some issues because a `div` is created few times.

[image]

If I remove the `CascadingValue`, the `CascadingParameter` doesn't have a value and so it raises an error. But, if I add some vanilla HTML code, the tabs from the HTML is working as expected (in the following screenshot, the first gray space is the render of the Blazor component, the second one the HTML code)

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I have to add the *setup* only in the *firstRender*.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        dotNetHelper = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Helpers.setDotNetHelper", dotNetHelper);

        // Setup the tabs
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", TabId);
    }
}
```